# There is no nontrivial ring homomorphism between two commutative rings with unity and characteristic of distinct primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following is an old exam question and the question is: Show that there is no nontrivial ring homomorphism between two commutative rings with identity if their characteristics are distinct primes.

So, I read the solution to this problem: [Prove that the only homomorphism between two cyclic groups with distinct prime orders is the trivial one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156030/prove-that-the-only-homomorphism-between-two-cyclic-groups-with-distinct-prime-o)

Would the argument to my question be basically the same thing since rings have an additive abelian group structure (although it is not necessarily cyclic) or would I need to expand (I'm going to guess its a yes). If so I'm thinking this should be done by contradiction, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this or where the contradiction would come in. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $f$ is a homomorphism from a ring of characteristic $p$ into one of characteristic $q$, then $qf(1)=f(p1)=pf(1)=0$. Use this to show that $f(1)=0$.

Comment: I just don't exactly understand why $qf(1) = f(p1)$. What is the trick here?

Comment: $qx=0$ for all $x$ in the target ring, $f(p1)=f(0)=0$.

Comment: Right! I just realized that!

Comment: Wait, $pf(1) = 0$ doen't make sense to me because we aren't in the domain of $f$. Also, to show that $f(1) = 0$ don't we need the nonexistence of zero divisors which we don't have?

Comment: The multiplication notation is a bit of an abuse. It's repeated addition. You're not actually multiplying by $p$.

Comment: Alright! I understand now! thanks!

Comment: @C.EU.RL no problem.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see the comments below. Whether this answer is correct depends on exactly how "homomorphism" is defined; if homomorphisms must preserve multiplicative unity, then this is correct, but otherwise this is incorrect. Basically, this hinges on whether we have a "primitive symbol" for the multiplicative identity or not.

---

One way to do it is to look at the subgroups $R'$ and $S'$ of the additive groups of $R$ and $S$ generated by $1_R$ and $1_S$, respectively. Any ring homomorphism from $R$ to $S$ must send $1_R$ to $1_S$, and so induces a group homomorphism from $R'$ to $S'$. But:

- What sort of groups are $R'$ and $S'$?
- What are the orders of $R'$ and $S'$?

(NOTE: $R'$ and $S'$ are actually sub*rings* of $R$ and $S$, but we don't need that.)

Comment: $1$ could be mapped to something other than $1$. Of course essentially the argument works, but technically this is wrong.

Comment: I was assuming the multiplicative identity was part of the language, so any homomorphism must by defnition send $1_R$ to $1_S$. But this is a good point.

Comment: Well, there seems to be some disagreement on this point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism demands that unity be preserved, but http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4517/Lectures/L7.html does not.

Comment: But here the suggestion that trivial homomorphisms exist implies that $1$ need not be sent to $1$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. (I cringe at that, though, since if we leave the multiplicative identity out of our language then rings don't form a variety.)

Comment: You're of course entitled to preserve my nitpicking for posterity, but you could also make the slight modification that makes it correct in all cases. $1$ is not special in generating a cyclic additive subgroup.